# Firebase StreamBuilder<User?> not working as expected

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have this code for checking for user session of Firebase:

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    print('stream: ${snapshot.connectionState}');

    Widget widget = loadingWidget;

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      widget = loadingWidget;
    }else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
        widget = GamePage();
      }else{
        widget = HomeScreen();
      }       
    }
    return widget;

  },
),
```

Now the problem is that when I run this print statement to check the connection state flow, this is what I get:

```
flutter: stream: ConnectionState.waiting
flutter: stream: ConnectionState.active
flutter: stream: ConnectionState.waiting
flutter: stream: ConnectionState.waiting
flutter: stream: ConnectionState.active
```

so now I have an issue that I need to sort of debounce these flickering in states to avoid creating and disposing widgets multiple times until settled, because now my loadingWidget keeps lagging and is not smooth because of the on and off effect.

I tried to create like a debouncer which is a futureBuilder that waits for a future delay of 200-500 milliseconds but the issue is the flickering stage doesn't have a certain amount of time and I had to make the delay 1 second to fully exclude the flickering, but this is inefficient for me.

Did anyone encounter this problem or have a solution that might work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()` to handle this situation, and it can help avoid unnecessary UI updates when the stream emits the same data multiple times.

```dart
StreamBuilder<User?>(
  // Update the subject with distinct user values
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().distinct(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    print('stream: ${snapshot.connectionState}');

    Widget widget = loadingWidget;

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      widget = loadingWidget;
    }else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
        widget = GamePage();
      }else{
        widget = HomeScreen();
      }       
    }

    return widget;
  },
),
```

Comment: thanks @pskink I will update the answer.

Comment: This did not solve the issue, yet still the flickering happens, no changes. I'm working on a solution where I don't directly use the Streambuilder, but I will be using a listener and ChangeNotifier to filter the listener and produce a more efficient stream, I will update the post once I'm finished